# Cordova/Angular/Ionic iOS App stops working after date change (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an issue when executing an hybrid app and then accessing to Settings > General > Date & Time (App now is in background), I proceed to set up a date previous than the current one, after that, Javascript doesn't seem to work: I press buttons that should trigger functions defined to my Angular controller and don't seem to work.
After setting up the current day, the app starts working correctly.
This issue was tested on an iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1.1
Apache Cordova: 4.2.0
AngularJS: 1.3
Ionic: 1.3.11

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.